# extracting output data from typed_output_tensor in TFlite

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Thanks in advance for your support.

I'm trying to get the output of a tensor after the inference on a .tflite U-net neural network. I'm using Tensorflow lite image classification code as a baseline.

I need to adapt the code for a segmentation task. My question is how I can access the output of the inferenced model (which 128x128x1) and write the result into an image?

I already debugged the code and explored many different approaches. Unfortunately, I'm not confident with the C++ language. What I found is that the command: `interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0)` should be what I need, as also referenced here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#loading_a_model. However, I cannot access the 128x128 tensor generated by the network.

You can find the code at the address: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/770481fb3e9126f9a29db5667f528e450d54d719/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/label_image.cc

The interesting part is here (lines 217 -224):

```
const float threshold = 0.001f;

std::vector<std::pair<float, int>> top_results;

int output = interpreter->outputs()[0];
TfLiteIntArray* output_dims = interpreter->tensor(output)->dims;
// assume output dims to be something like (1, 1, ... ,size)
auto output_size = output_dims->data[output_dims->size - 1];
```

I expect the values saved in an image or an alternative way of saving the output tensor